# Tensorflow: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I training a VGG16 NN with GPU using TensorFlow, it always show me `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` and always stops with the error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.`

I searched the internet with those message and got some tips:

- set `config.gpu_options.allow_growth` to `True`.
- set `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` to a smaller fraction like `0.6`.
- set smaller `batch size`.

But these tips don't work, the process runs just like nothing changed.

Here is my hardware:

- GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1060
- Memory: 3G + 4G(shared memory)

I monitored the usage of GPU using `nvidia-smi`, and below is the detail.

Before Running:

```
Thu Apr 19 14:21:59 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 388.31                 Driver Version: 388.31                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8     7W /  N/A |    587MiB /  3072MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7300    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
|    0      8244    C+G   ...6)\Youdao\YoudaoNote\YNoteCefRender.exe N/A      |
|    0      9988    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0     10696    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     10808    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     11024    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     11092    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe              N/A      |
|    0     13076    C+G   ...ogram Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe N/A      |
|    0     14664    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Process begin:

```
Thu Apr 19 14:24:23 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 388.31                 Driver Version: 388.31                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P2    28W /  N/A |   1133MiB /  3072MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7300    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
|    0      9988    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0     10696    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     10808    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     11024    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     11092    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe              N/A      |
|    0     13076    C+G   ...ogram Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe N/A      |
|    0     14404      C   ...ools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\python.exe N/A      |
|    0     14664    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After 10 steps:

```
Thu Apr 19 14:30:40 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 388.31                 Driver Version: 388.31                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P2    31W /  N/A |   2595MiB /  3072MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7300    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
|    0      9988    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0     10696    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     10808    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     11024    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     11092    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe              N/A      |
|    0     13076    C+G   ...ogram Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe N/A      |
|    0     14404      C   ...ools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\python.exe N/A      |
|    0     14664    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After 60 steps:
some message showed, but can still run

```
2018-04-19 14:33:56.384528: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-19 14:33:56.423080: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 1932735232 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-19 14:33:56.474281: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 1739461632 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Thu Apr 19 14:36:13 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 388.31                 Driver Version: 388.31                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   63C    P2    33W /  N/A |   2602MiB /  3072MiB |     43%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7300    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
|    0      9988    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0     10696    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     10808    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     11024    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     11092    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe              N/A      |
|    0     13076    C+G   ...ogram Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe N/A      |
|    0     14404      C   ...ools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\python.exe N/A      |
|    0     14664    C+G   ...osoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After 170 steps:

About eight hundreds lines message showed, then the process stopped with errors

About eight hundreds lines:

```
2018-04-19 14:49:35.688274: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

Stopped with some errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: input/input/div/_79 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_111_input/input/div", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16_train_and_test.py", line 212, in <module>
    train()
  File "vgg16_train_and_test.py", line 124, in train
    coord.join(threads)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 234, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\DevTools\Anaconda3\envs\py36_tfg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: input/input/div/_79 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_111_input/input/div", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: A colleague of mine uses a gpu of NVIDIA GTX 950 with 8G Memory(2 + 5.9), he encountered 3 lines of the message `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` after about 230 steps, and then his process never stopped after that.

Comment: I used to get this error from time to time when running CUDA programs. Restart your computer and then, before you open up any other programs (including your internet browser), try rerunning your code. That always fixed it for me

Comment: Thanks, though it sounds not a good idea, I will try it later.

Comment: I tried twice, however, it looks like worse. The error message comes up on the first step, then the process stopped after 150 steps.

Comment: Compared PCs between mine with my colleague's, I found there is a difference: my computer has only one Discrete Graphics, but his has two(one Integrated graphics, another Discrete Graphics). i.e. all of my processes running in the computer run on the solo GPU, and they'll interactive when there are no more memory. So I guess, it is the lack of Integrated graphics makes the error appears over and over.